# How to automatically change wallpaper from interfacelift?

Tags: desktop-background

This is something I'd like to work on. There is this site called [Interfacelift](http://interfacelift.com/wallpaper/downloads/date/any/) which offers really good wallpapers for any screen resolution and is updated regularly. The site which has a google+ page, has agreed to provide beta testers with a **MediaRSS link**.

*Is there any way I can use this to allow ubuntu to change my wallpaper automatically to the newest wallpaper submitted on Interfacelift?*

They somehow use this to create .theme files for windows to create dynamic wallpaper changing. I was wondering if something similar can be done in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Reading their terms of service, the only thing you can get via automated means is the XML RSS feed. Even then, it feels like they don't really want you to do be doing that to pull down high-res backgrounds as they discuss how it would affect the site.

http://interfacelift.com/website/terms_of_service.php

> This web site is intended to be accessed via standard web browser
>   software such as Apple Safari, Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft Internet
>   Explorer, and similar products via direct interaction by a human. With
>   the exception of publicly accessible RSS feeds provided in XML format,
>   the web site and its associated files are not meant to be accessed via
>   any automated means such as by scripts or bots or 3rd party
>   applications.
>
> Be aware that if you utilize an automated means of accessing or
>   downloading this web site, in whole or in part, your access to the
>   site may be prevented, terminated, delayed, or slowed either
>   temporarily or permanently, especially if you attempt to download more
>   than 3 large files simulateously. This is necessary in order to
>   protect the user-experience of the web site for those who access it in
>   the manner envisioned by it's authors and architects.
>
> Please understand that automated access to the site, via scripts,
>   bots, or other similar means can have the effect of seriously
>   degrading the performance of the web site or incurring significant
>   additional costs to its operators without sufficient revenue generated
>   to cover those costs. Keep in mind, that even minor infractions
>   against this policy can have a large negative effect when combined
>   with similar actions by other users.
>
> We ask that you respect the above guidelines so that we may continue
>   to offer the web site as a free resource to the world. We prefer to
>   use our resources, both human and financial, to improve and expand the
>   features and content of the web site. Your cooperation is essential.

That said, if they would allow you to do that it would probably require a custom job to run and create the necessary file to point to. I don't believe there is anything already available to do this (I've briefly searched)

Comment: You're right, but with a MediaRSS which will provide updates about new wallpapers, can I set it as my wallpaper?

Answer (score 1):

As the TOS states they don't want you to access their site with scripts or bots and can result in a ban from the site; but for programming purposes, it is possible and quite easy.

If you use a program like [Variety](http://peterlevi.com/variety/) and an RSS feed it is possible. The website offers paid RSS feeds or you can use [Google sheets](http://sheets.google.com) to scrape the site at random intervals and get new images and then convert it to an MRSS feed to be used by the program.